# Is there a good way to retrieve company summary from wikipedia?

Tags: search, wikipedia

My question is not about parsing.

I have been looking through the wikipedia API. I need to search for companies and get a one sentence summary. It's working good, the only problem I have is when I need to disambiguate. It's hard for my code to know whether "dropbox (service)" or "dropbox (band)" is the dropbox company my user is looking for.
I tried to put the word "company" in the query, expecting it to work like a google search, but unfortunately it didn't.

so my question is: is there an easy way to disambiguate the results I get by telling wikipedia it is a "company" that I want?

Comment: Look at the categories of the search results

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for companies only then consider using their full names instead of short forms. In case of Dropbox, the name of the company is Dropbox, Inc. If you search for Dropbox, Inc in Wikipedia you will be redirected to the page Dropbox(Service) which i believe is the page youre looking for.

If you dont have the resources to have the name of the company in the perfect format, then consider using **Category:Companies** to refine your results further.

When you get to the page, you can mine for the extract of the company by using the Mediawiki API as follows

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Dropbox%20(service)

Note: The extract is called section0 in MediaWiki

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying Wikidata. Wikidata are a multilingual factual database of everything, and they have a query interface at query.wikidata.org. The language the interface uses is called SPARQL. For instance, if you're interested in a list of well-known cats, https://w.wiki/W4W is your query. More details can be found at https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service.

Answer (score 0):

```
import wikipedia


print(wikipedia.summary("COMPANY_NAME"))
```

Try to filter out the companies by categories - there is a list provided in the end of the page:

```
xx = wikipedia.page("Dropbox")
xx.title
print(xx.categories)
```

Comment: Fine and dandy where you know *COMPANY_NAME*. Can user2249621 get exact company names from their customer(s)?